# Finding Time Between Current Time and TimeDate in PHP

Tags: php, time

I'm having some trouble finding the difference between two TimeDates in PHP. Here's what I've got.

```
$endTime = new DateTime($row['endTime']); // "$row['endTime']" is from a mysql database
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $endTime->diff($now);
echo $interval->format("%h:%i:%s");
```

For an example, if endTime was '2014-01-08 01:51:40', and the current time was 
'2014-01-09 01:54:42', it was be displayed as '24:03:02'. I also need to figure out how to do something like:

```
if($endTime > $now){
    //run code
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What isn't working. Both snippets look ok to me (at a glance).

Comment: convert all to time-stamp and compare it

Comment: You don't need to convert DateTime objects to timestamps to compare them. They are comparable already.

Comment: as @JohnConde said you can compare two DateTime objects directly without to cast to any plain format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works (although I don't think the formatting of your interval is what you're probably looking for). As you can see you *can* compare DateTime objects without having to convert them into another format like a timestamp.

```
$endTime = new DateTime('tomorrow'); 
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$now = new DateTime();
if($endTime > $now){
    $interval = $endTime->diff($now);
    echo $interval->format("%h:%i:%s");
}
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/JAnOo)

Comment: Wow thanks! That was easier than I thought. However, I have a few questions. If there's more than 24 hours left, would it display as 25 hours, or as 0 hours? Also, is there an easy way I can have the minutes and seconds display as ':01' rather than ':1'? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: All of that is handled by the formatting parameters you pass to `format()`. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/working-with-dates-and-times-in-php/) that should demonstrate how to do a lot of this.